#  Remote registry always null when different user

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, remote-registry

I am creating a c# windows form application that goes read registry on remote computers.

```
RegistryKey regKey = RegistryKey
                        .OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, pc, RegistryView.Registry64)
                        .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources");
```

When i run the application from USER1 it works because my remote computers are always logged in with USER1.

Now if i run it with USER2 my regKey is always equal to NULL, no matter what.

On my remote computers, in Component Services, i allowed the service : REMOTE REGISTRY.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: What the difference between the permissions of User1 and User2?

Comment: Has user2 ever logged onto the machines? If not then it wont have any registry entries to check as you are searching CurrentUser.

Comment: @abatishchev i cannot access to the domain to see what are the difference between the two users

Comment: @GazWinter i have 4 remote computers, USER2 only logged in onto 1 of them, i should at least see one of remote registry, but no my regKey is still NULL

Comment: try this to check permissions diff b/w User1 & User2 - `Accesschk "domain\user" -a *`. Download it from here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922

Comment: Frankly I'm surprised this even works as RegConnectRegistry() (invoked internally by OpenRemoteBaseKey) is not documented as supporting HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  I guess it must impersonate you on the server side and it just happens to work if your registry is already loaded at the time.  As a workaround you could try opening HKEY_USERS hive and "<SID>\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\..." key instead where <SID> is the account SID; I don't know how robust that is, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read HKEY_CURRENT_USER via remote registry, for the simple reason that there is no "current user" from the perspective of the remote registry service.

For example, would it be:

- The registry key you would see if you were logged on? (but you are not!)
- The registry key of the current logged-on user (What if there is none? What if more than one?)

It cannot just fetch your registry hive and load it because you may not have a roaming profile. It doesn't want to create one just so you can look at the registry.

So: HKEY_CURRENT_USER doesn't return anything for remote registry service. If you are interested in a particular user you might look under HKEY_USERS.